# Clion: Conditional compilation flags

Tags: c, clion, conditional-compilation

I have some conditional compilation flags across multiple source files, which looks as following :

```
#ifdef FLAG1
   code ...
#endif
```

I have these flags enabled in the `Makefile`, based on some conditions. Clion grays out the blocks of code that are within the flags and doesn't perform any syntax analysis on them. Is there a way to enable some flags directly in Clion?

Answer (score 1):

To add a preprocessor

```
add_definitions(-DFOO -DBAR ...)
```

See [this link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_definitions.html) for CMake's documentation.

Comment: Eclipse has a better and easier way to do this. Hope JetBrains makes a better IDE soon.

Comment: I believe Clion adds these during compiling, which doesn't solve my problem of it not performing analysis of the syntax if code is within the flags

Comment: CLion makes dry run of the compiler to extract definitions for each compilation unit. So the changes in CMake cause changes in syntax analysis.

Comment: You can set those in CMakeList.txt file.

Comment: try add  ```add_definitions(-DFLAG1)``` in  CMakeLists.txt

Comment: The OP was talking about Makefile, not about CMakeFiles. These are different toolchains.

Answer (score 1):

To make things work correctly, make sure that:

- your Makefile is in the root of your project in CLion, else it won't work, or at least didn't work for me
- make sure that in the *Arguments* field (on the screenshot) you provide all arguments you would do for a makefile to make all macro definitions (like -DFoo=bar). So if you run run make like `make USE_THIS=1 DEBUG=1`, type *USE_THIS=1 DEBUG=1* into this field and reload Makefile project.
  [image: screenshot of CLion Makefile config]